# Black space between 2 of my divs. I dont know how to remove them. Have tried a couple of things

Tags: html, css

[This is a screenshot of it. I want the label and the image both to fit inside the blue div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr6O3.png)

I want both of them to fit inside the blue div. But nothing i did worked. I read i should have them float left/right but it stills have the blank space. Set the margin on 0. Still the blank space.  The only thing that removed the blank space was line height on 0px. But this messed up the label placement. So i am kinda lost on this one

Html :

```
<div class="playerInfo">
<div class="playerChamp">
    <img src="profileIcon10.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
        <div class="playerName">
            <label for="male">Male</label>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.playerInfo {
      height:120px;
      width:130px;
      background:blue;
        border:solid 1px black;
  }

  .playerChamp {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background :red;
}

  .playerName {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background :red;
}
```

Comment: You're not accounting for two things .. 1 the border on the blue div makes it actually `118px` of usable space.  and `IMG` tag uses 2 more px unless you set it's border to `none`.  So with that said.  You'll need to extend the outer box to `124px;` or reduce the inner elements by a total of `4px`

Comment: Conversely ..  add `margin-top: -4px;` to `.playerName` will pull it up and you won't have the space between the two divs.

Comment: the margin-top worked. Thanks a bunch :D. The border was added after the problem. had nothing to do with it

Comment: I'll create an answer for you then if you'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `margin-top: -4px;` to `.playerName` will pull it up and you won't have the space between the two `divs`.

[SEE THE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m3xenqrn/1/)